# Navigating to the Anchor tag of a page

Tags: html, sharepoint, hyperlink, infopath, infopath2010

We are currently creating a Sharepoint Infopath form. I need to tag a section of the page in the infopath form. I know to insert hyperlink we can do it like

[image]

But how to navigate to the particular section of the page.

Comment: Create a div with unique ID and link to that (<a href="#idname">).

Comment: @rsn where do I create this div with unique ID

Comment: Where you want the page to navigate/scroll to, so above a certain section of your form for instance.

Comment: @rsn I cannot change anything on the page. I dont have access to change them on the page. I am new to this, may be I am not getting it

Comment: Ah, the infopath thing. Maybe this will help you: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50464/how-to-insert-a-named-hyperlink-anchor-in-infopath